# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.selectedProductDetails is null"

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have strange problem with render my components.

```
  <app-content-switcher :state="!!selectedProductDetails">
    <template slot="up">
      <product-d-p :product-id="selectedProductDetails.id">
        <template slot-scope="{data: product, loading, error}">
          <label v-if="loading">Loading</label>
          <div v-else-if="product">
            {{product}}
          </div>
          <label v-else-if="error">Error</label>
        </template>
      </product-d-p>
    </template>
    <template slot="down">
      Nope
    </template>
  </app-content-switcher>
```

AppContentSwitcher is very simple.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot
        name="up"
        v-if="state"
    />
    <slot
        name="down"
        v-else
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "AppContentSwitcher",
  props: {
    state: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

1. The problem is selectedProductDetails.id where selectedProductDetails is null.
2. I don't render this component if selectedProductDetails is null, two lines higher I set state in 'AppContentSwitcher', which shouldn't render this component.

What is wrong here? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find workaround. I created method:

```
getSelectedProductDetailsId: function (){
  return this.selectedProductDetails?.id
}
```

and it work :)

Still I don't understand why my first solution doesn't work.